# Solr logging of POST body

Tags: solr

Is there a way to make Solr log the body of a POST? I've been using the json API with POST and just noticed Solr only appears to be logging the url that's called, not the body/data of the request.

Comment: That's not a reasonable requirement I think, the body could be huge. And there is no such config options in solr doc: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Configuring+Logging

Comment: I have the same requirement. I want to reproduce Exceptions coming up after a post. But without the content of the post body I cannot reproduce the behaviour.